# Having trouble rigging a jacket I got from sketchfab properly with my character

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I downloaded a varsity jacket from sketchfab and am having trouble properly rigging it with my character. When I move the arms, torso parts of the jacket that aren't connected to the arms move also, which can be seen in the following images.
[image: Armature in default stance, which I matched to the default position the jacket was in when I downloaded it.]
[image: unwanted deformations in the jacket torso can be see here]
[image]

I'm thinking the problem lies within the weight paint data for the jacket.

To assign weight paint data to the jacket, I essentially stole the it from the body mesh by using a Data transfer modifier on the jacket, setting it to vertex data and 'nearest vertex' so the jacket would copy the weight of the nearest body mesh vertex. This worked somewhat, but gave me the problem shown here where I had unwanted parts of the jacket I deforming.

I tried manually weight painting to see if I could fix it at all or even weight paint some parts from scratch, but no luck there.
My guess is the data transfer didn't work perfectly as the body mesh was pretty different from the jacket mesh (body is quads and jacket is tris btw) and resulted in some janky weight data, but regardless I'm still not totally sure what the fix is...

My blend file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cpS6rRqYW3g1gGZuAPkX_tLcfJCGelfe/view?usp=sharing) if you need it, thank you for reading my post and any help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Select all in Edit mode, merge by distance (M), maybe convert tris to quads (Alt J), parent again With Automatic Weights, and it seems to work fine

Comment: well....tbh...if you bought the jacket as it is now in your blend file...i think, it isn't worth the money you gave. It's not even closed: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI3ns.png that's a pic of the right arm/side. Nevertheless moonboots comment helps a lot. or is it intended that the jacket has holes under the arms? sorry, i am not  a fashion expert.

Comment: thankyou this seems to have worked, such a huge help! and luckily this model was free on sketchfab, which i guess is why the holes were left in the arms lol

Answer (score 0):

Select all in *Edit* mode, merge by distance (<kbd>M</kbd>), maybe convert tris to quads (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), parent again *With Automatic Weights*, and it seems to work fine. You could even simplify the topology with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, it's always better to have a low-poly mesh to animate.